# How to optimize NTLM SSPI authentication - apache web server

Tags: apache, ntlm, sspi

We have NTLM authentication for our application using SSPIAuth on apache for which we have done following configuration in our apache vhosts file:

```
<Location />


    SetHandler dispatcher-handler
    AuthName "A Protected Place"
    AuthType SSPI      
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIDomain IT
    SSPIOmitDomain On          
    SSPIOfferBasic Off          
    SSPIBasicPreferred Off     
    SSPIUsernameCase lower
    SSPIPerRequestAuth Off 
    SSPIOfferSSPI On
    SSPIPackage NTLM
    Require valid-user  

   </Location>
```

We also have keepalive settings as follow:

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 150
KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

My question is:

1) How can I optimize it if there are any options? I am not too aware of how this authentication works.
2) How can I enable logs for SSPI auth to check how much time is AD taking?

We have a windows based server with apache 2.2

Comment: found this related article [KeepAlive usage]( https://abdussamad.com/archives/169-Apache-optimization:-KeepAlive-On-or-Off.html) useful with more context info for Q1